# Bootstrap causing javascript errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I am using a bootstrap template that has a single sidebar. I am trying to place a highchart on the initial index page of this template, but apparently the template is causing issues and making my graph not show up at all

The template with the code is located at http://pastebin.com/wBvdG2J1  (for some reason I can't get it to format very well for the post so I will leave it there).

At first I thought it was my javascript, but then I tried just it alone and it performed as intended

```
 <div id="container" class="resize" style=" width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto "></div>

        <label for="numberInput">Enter Number Code:</label><input type="text" id="numberInput" />
        <input type="button" value="Enter" id="enter"/>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#enter').click(function() {

            sgaxml = "https://sga.quickbase.com/db/bjmdensiu?apptoken=beadyrucxguavbx5isubd6iaqpe&act=API_DoQuery&query={14.EX." + $("#numberInput").val() + "}&clist=7.24.25.26.27.28.29.30.31.32.33.34.35.36.37";

            console.log(sgaxml);

            // Load the data from the XML file 
                $.get(sgaxml, function(xml) {

                // Split the lines
                var xml = $(xml).find('record');

                var options = {
                        chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Components Over Time'
                 },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: []
                },
                    yAxis: {
                         title: {
                     text: 'Concentration%'
            }
        },
        series: []
    };


// Variables for the component series

var seriesH = {
        name: 'Hydrogen',
        data: []
    };

     var seriesHe = {
        name: 'Helium',
        data: []
    };

var seriesO = {
        name: 'Oxygen',
        data: []
    };

var seriesHs = {
        name: 'Hydrogen Sulfide',
        data: []
    };

var seriesN = {
        name: 'Nitrogen',
        data: []
    };

var seriesC = {
        name: 'Carbon Dioxide',
        data: []
    };

var seriesM = {
        name: 'Methane',
        data: []
    };

var seriesE = {
        name: 'Ethane',
        data: []
    };

var seriesP = {
        name: 'Propane',
        data: []
    };

var seriesIb = {
        name: 'Iso-Butane',
        data: []
    };

var seriesNb = {
        name: 'N-Butane',
        data: []
    };

var seriesIp = {
        name: 'Iso-Pentane',
        data: []
    };

var seriesNp = {
        name: 'N-Pentane',
        data: []
    };

var seriesHex = {
        name: 'Hexanes+',
        data: []
    };

xml.each(function (i, record) {
        options.xAxis.categories.push(new Date(parseInt($(record).find('sample_date').text())));
    seriesH.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('hydrogen').text()));
    seriesHe.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('helium').text()));
    seriesO.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('oxygen').text()));
    seriesHs.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('hydrogen_sulfide').text()));
    seriesN.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('nitrogen').text()));
    seriesC.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('co2').text()));
        seriesM.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('methane').text()));
        seriesE.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('ethane').text()));
    seriesP.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('propane').text()));
    seriesIb.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('iso_butane').text()));
    seriesNb.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('n_butane').text()));
    seriesIp.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('iso_pentane').text()));
    seriesNp.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('n_pentane').text()));
    seriesHex.data.push(parseFloat($(record).find('hexanes_').text()));
    });

console.log(seriesO.data);  

if($.isNumeric(seriesH.data[0])){options.series.push(seriesH)};
if($.isNumeric(seriesHe.data[0])){options.series.push(seriesHe)};
if($.isNumeric(seriesO.data[0])){options.series.push(seriesO)};
if($.isNumeric(seriesHs.data[0])){options.series.push(seriesHs)};
if($.isNumeric(seriesN.data[0])){options.series.push(seriesN)};
if($.isNumeric(seriesC.data[0])){options.series.push(seriesC)};
if($.isNumeric(seriesM.data[0])){options.series.push(seriesM)};
if($.isNumeric(seriesE.data[0])){options.series.push(seriesE)};
if($.isNumeric(seriesP.data[0])){options.series.push(seriesP)};
    if($.isNumeric(seriesIb.data[0])){options.series.push(seriesIb)};
if($.isNumeric(seriesNb.data[0])){options.series.push(seriesNb)};
if($.isNumeric(seriesIp.data[0])){options.series.push(seriesIp)};
if($.isNumeric(seriesNp.data[0])){options.series.push(seriesNp)};
if($.isNumeric(seriesHex.data[0])){options.series.push(seriesHex)};
    console.log('options: ', options);

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});

});                          

});
```

I checked the console and notice that when I run the code with the template I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEvent' of undefined highcharts.js:304

I've looked over it and can't figure out why it's not working with the template...maybe I am overlooking something?

Comment: First thing you'll want to do is not use two versions of jQuery in your template. You've got one reference to v1.11.1 and one to v1.8.2. Remove one or the other but make sure you load jQuery before jQuery UI.

Comment: Also Mustache.min.js and Mustache.js one after the other. Probably doesn't matter, but why?

Comment: FWIW, no errors here: http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/wgaugp59/.

Comment: Ok, I figured this out thanks to Joshua's comment, it made me stop and realize that I was actually calling jquery after highcharts and highcharts required. The mustache.js repeat happened when I stuck jquery in a second time also